# Split flat file into multiple files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, ssis-2012

I need to create a package which splits the huge flat file into multiple flat files.

I have flat file which has 20 million rows and now I need to split this flat file (Each flat file needs to have 55 k rows)

Example:- if there are 111 rows in total, I would have to create 3 files.

file1.txt  will have 1-55 rows
file2.txt will have 55-110 rows
file3.txt will have 1  rows
.

What options do I have?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 for this project.

Comment: are you able to or have the ability to use a script task or are you looking to use a data flow

Comment: I am not good in writing scripts but I am open for constructive suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this... its pretty rudimentary and I am sure that someone will point out that it is not going to be the most efficient thing but its a solid option. Note that you will need to add some try catch error handling.

```
            int recper = 0; // this is where you will assign the number of records per file 
            int reccount = 0;
            int filecount = 1;
            string filename = "testfilename";
            string networkDirectory = @"c:\fakepath\";
            string fileToRead = @"c:\fakepath\textfile.txt";

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileToRead,Encoding.Default,true))
            {
                while (reader.Peek() > 0)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(networkDirectory, filename + filecount + ".txt"), true, Encoding.Default))
                    {
                        writer.Write(reader.ReadLine());
                    }
                    reccount++;
                    // checks on each iteration of the while loop to see if the 
                    // current record count matches the number of records per file
                    // if sso reset reccount and change increment filecount to change the file name 
                    if (reccount == recper)
                    {
                        reccount = 0;
                        filecount++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you tell me  where did you insert the condition that 1 flat file should have only 50 k rows. I am sorry for asking you this silly question.

Comment: sorry i forgot to comment that in in the code it would be the recper variable . You can see in the while loop that each iteration checks to see if the current reccount equals the recper or records per file  and if so then it increments the file count to change the name of the output file and then resents the reccount variable to start counting again. I will edit my answer to show this

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do this is in a dataflow:

First use your method of choice to add a "Row Number" column to your data flow (unless there is already one in your flat file output, in which case skip this step and use that):

https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=add+rownumber+column+to+ssis+dataflow&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=add+rownumber+column+to+ssis+dataflow&gs_l=hp....0.0.0.6218...........0._Qm62-0x_YQ

Then add a MultiCast transformation to your dataflow, and use the row number to split the stream and send it to different destinations:

Row 1 - 55k, -> File1

Row 55001 - 110k -> File2

etc.

Comment: I have several millions of record and going by this logic, I will need 300 +  multicast transformation? Any alternative approach?